# Dialogflow v2 Actions on Google response timeout

Tags: google-places-api, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot, fulfillment

Hi I have a timeout problem to get a json response; I am using google places API to look for the closest location.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

```
const PlaceSearch = require("./node_modules/googleplaces/lib/NearBySearch.js");
const PlaceDetailsRequest = require("./node_modules/googleplaces/lib/PlaceDetailsRequest.js");

app.intent('Ask Location', conv => {conv.ask(new Permission({context: 'To start',permissions: 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION',}));});

app.intent('geolocation.intent', (conv,params,granted) =>{   
if(granted){    
    var coordinates = conv.device.location.coordinates;
    var location = [coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude];
    var searchParameters = {
        location: location,
        name:'Store Name',
        radius:10000    
    };     
    var config = {
        apiKey:'#####',
        outputFormat:'json'
    };
    var placeSearch = new PlaceSearch(config.apiKey, config.outputFormat);
    var placeDetailsRequest = new PlaceDetailsRequest(config.apiKey, config.outputFormat);     
    placeSearch(searchParameters, function (error, search_response) {
        if(search_response.status === 'OK'){             
            placeDetailsRequest({reference: search_response.results[0].reference}, function (error, details_response) {
            conv.ask(`Your closest store is at ${details_response.result.formatted_address}.`);
            });            
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the error message or give details about your timeout problem.

Comment: Could you try measuring the time taken by places-api? Dialogflow has a 5 second timeout limit https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/95#issuecomment-405759917

Comment: As @AhmetEmreKılınç said - it would really help us if you updated your question to include details about the "problem" that you're having and any logs that might help illustrate the problem. If you're testing this on the simulator, what shows up in the "error" or "debug" tabs?

Comment: Hi to everyone, thanks for your help. I got the message "MalformedResponse
'final_response' must be set." in the console it through me the next ERROR: "Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?
". I used to have the same code in Dialogflow V1 and it works. I was reading I need to use promises.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue using a request to Google API via URL; and using a promise.

```
const request = require("request");
app.input("geolocation.intent", conv => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      ...
      if (error) {
        ...
        reject(...);
      } else {
        ...
        resolve(...);
      }
  }).then(result => {
    const address = result.address;
    conv.ask('Your closest store is...');
  }).catch(error => {
    conv.close('Error in Promise');
  });
});
```

What I learned is that in Dialogflow API v2 you need to use promises when you make a request.